# Automatically fix lint problems only on a specific file

Tags: npm, command-line, eslint

I am running `npm run lint -- --fix` from command line to automatically fix lint errors, but this command creates fixes on the entire project.

I've been searching the [documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface) to find out how to run the automatic fix on a specific file instead of the entire project, but I couldn't find a way.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Using ESLint from the CLI should fix it:

```
eslint --fix "C:\code\hello-world.js"
```

[ESLint CLI documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface)

Answer (score 8):

The solution works great, this is just a quick tip for yarn/mac users:

```
yarn eslint --fix "src/ui/screens/HelloWorld.js"
```

Comment: Without the quotes also worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try for TypeScript file:

```
npx tslint src/code/HelloWord.ts --fix
```

For folder:

```
npx tslint src/code/*.ts --fix
```

You can check which command executes in background when you run `npm run lint -- --fix` in `package.json` and use it to lint only required directory/file.

Here how it may look in `package.json` example:

```
"scripts": {
     ...
    "lint": "npx tslint src/**/*.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npx tslint src/**/*.ts --fix",
     ...
}
```